# All fields in an object not being sent to WCF service...MVC3

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a class in my WCF app with properties in it:

```
        [DataContract(Namespace = "http://www.ramquest.com/types")]
      public class NewOrderPropertyDto
      {
        [DataMember]
        public int ID { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DataMember]
        public string Address { get; set; }
     }
```

I use this to transfer data to the WCF service. I populate all fields in the NewOrderPropertyDto object in the main app and send it to a WCF method:

```
 var dto = new NewOrderPropertyDto();
  dto.ID = 1;
  dto.Description = "test";
  dto.Address = "123 my street";
  var wcfService = new ServicesClient();
  wcfService.GetData(dto);
```

The WCF method looks like this:

```
   public bool GetData(NewOrderPropertyDto data)
    {
      var id = data.ID; //ID is 1 as expected
      var addy =   data.Address; //the Address field is null
   }
```

When the data gets to the WCF service only the Address field is null. Has anyone ever encountered this before? Also, is there a tool is can use to see where the nulling is occurring? Thanks

Comment: Was the address field added after the initial web reference was created?  If so you may just need to update the web reference in the client project.

Comment: It was added after and the reference was updated

Comment: Does the WSDL of the service you're referencing include the Address property?

Comment: no it doesnt...but the wsdl doesnt have a reference to anything property related. the xsd files do, and i see my Address property along with everything else in there

Comment: For your other question much of the WCF plumbing is baked into classes that you can't step through.  However you can turn on message logging to see the raw XML passed over: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751526.aspx

Comment: If all else fails you can remove and re-add the reference.